# Passive participial clauses

Tags: past-participles, participles, participial

Ive found the following example:

> I heard my name being shouted.

In this case, they use an passive participle.

But if you want to connect two sentences, you do the following:

> The house was built last year. It was sold yesterday.

to

> The house built last year was sold yesterday.

Why don't they use a passive participial there like

> The house was built last year was sold yesterday.

Is the following correct?:

Let's say I have the two sentences:

> The house has been built last year. It has been recently sold.

would it be

> The house been built last year, has been recently sold.

or would it be

> The house built last year, has been recently sold.

I'm just wondering, why I do not use the auxiliary verb in passive past.

Comment: _Built last year_ acts as an adjective phrase identifying the house.

Comment: Questions starting with "Why don't they have ...?" all have the same answer: (a) there is no **they**, and (b) nobody knows why some individual phrases and words stick around and others don't.  That would take recordings of every time a word was spoken for the last few centuries, and those are hard to come by.

Comment: "Built last year acts as an adjective phrase identifying the house." I thought its an participle.

Comment: @JohnLawler Hey, I gave that answer once and it was downvoted. I guess if an established scholar says "nobody knows", this is a pearl of wisdom. If an indigent vagabond like myself says it, it's jejune and worthy of being tossed in the fire.

Comment: It's the truth in many cases. But not everybody wants to know the rules; some just want to think they're right.

Comment: Don't you see 'The house was built last year was sold yesterday' is simply wrong? 'It has been recently sold' is a matter of choice but 'The house has been built last year' is again, simply wrong, as is 'The house been built…'